# Jenkins email send remote server cucumber report

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement let me explain scenario,

- Their is COMPUTER-A (Jenkins Server) through which we triggered pipeline build
- First Step it will create VM (COMPUTER-B) in vlab machine and get the IP
- Second Step it will execute testsuites.sh in COMPUTER-B through ssh below is pseudo-code

  ```
  steps {
    script {
      sh """
        ssh -i id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${USER}@${env.IP} "nohup /home/testsuites.sh > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null & "
      """
    }
  }
  ```

  this script is run in background "mvn clean test" which will run all test case and generate cucumber report at the end of build.

  till this working fine.

  Since its run in background jenkins job will not going to wait & will move to next stage
- Third Step Jenkins Server COMPUTER-A will send success mail

Now the requirement is once the build is success i need to send the cucumber test report through another mail. How to notify the jenkins job in COMPUTER-A (Since its already completed) to sent mail with cucumber report file which is their in remote server COMPUTER-B.

i can run corn job to check for build success , but how to notify the jenkins to send email with the cucumber test report.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Quiet Period

```
node {
    build job: 'FetchCucumberReport',
          quietPeriod: 60,// in secs -->1min
          wait: false
}
```

So what the above code does is it will trigger `FetchCucumberReport` Job after a 1 minute. If you roughly know how long the test cases will take to complete all tasks ( lets say 4 hours) then set `quietPeriod:14400`(seconds) and it will trigger the build after 4 hours.

**UPDATED**
You will have to look into API calls https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

An e.g

```
curl -X POST -u user:password http://localhost:8080/job/FetchCucumberReport/build
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i cannot decide approximate time because if test cases increases it will increase time also. and the cucumber reports will be in COMPUTER-B remote server, from Jenkins Server COMPUTER-A i need to send mail along with that reports how to access that cucumber report file which is their in remote server

Comment: If that's the case, you will have to look into REST API calls to Jenkins to Build the Project let's call it 'SendCucumberReport'.. Basically once the test cases are done you can do a Curl to Jenkins and trigger the job(which will fetch the report from Computer B using curl/ssh/scp up to you) or You can send the report then trigger the Job either way it's how you wan to design it.

Comment: Did it help ? or are you still facing issues ?

Comment: If the issue is resolved...Please select the correct answer so that others who face similar issues will benefit..If not, please add the issues you are still facing.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger a build as soon as your long running job is finished, which just emails the results:

```
curl -X POST http://user:password@<jenkins-url>:8080/job/test/build
```

If the job can run on the same machine it should be easy to gather the results, if not, you could just copy the artifacts via scp.

But I think that another approach might be better suited for your problem. Just let the job run as long as it takes, then you can send the email afterwards much easier. If you would like to trigger another job before, you could trigger another job which runs on the same machine.

Maybe creating a temporary jenkins slave might be the best idea. You can also do this via the REST API:
[Creating-node-with-the-REST-API](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003896171-Creating-node-with-the-REST-API)